# В чем преимущества Route Model Binding?

Tags: laravel

Есть у меня код, в котором вроде бы все понятно.

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 * 
 * @param string $slug
 * @return \Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function show(string $slug): \Illuminate\View\View
{
   $post = Post::where('slug', $slug)
               ->where('status', 1) // 
               ->with('reviews')
               ->firstOrFail();

   return view('post.show', compact('post'));
}
```

Однако, более опытные коллеги, сделали замечание, что лучше бы применить Route Model Binding. Говорят, должна улучшится читаемость да и код будет проще.

Однако, при таком подходе, мне придется:

1. В модели указать Sling как ключ для поиска.
2. Отдельно подгрузить отношения через load().
3. Прописать в модели resolveRouteBinding(), дабы можно было применить where().

Собственно... Кода становится не меньше и теперь он не так очевиден т.к разбросан по файлам, а не прописан в одном месте. Так в чем преимущества Route Model Binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея в том, что конструкцию вида:

```
Post::where('slug', $slug)
    ->where('status', 1)
```

Вы можете использовать в куче контроллеров и методов. Потом добавится еще какой-нибудь параметр и Вам понадобится добавить их во все контроллеры.

Да есть решение через scope

```
public function scopeActive($builder)
{
    $builder->where('status', 1);
}

public function scopeActiveSlug($builder, string $slug)
{
    $builder->where('slug', $slug)->active();
}

... 

Post::activeSlug($slug);
```

Но и здесть остаётся дубли `Post::activeSlug($slug)`. Возникает идея, а что если на вход будет приходить сразу нужный пост. Как в случае с инжектированием зависимостей из сервис контейнеров.

В результате можно сделать следующее. В `RouteServiceProvider` добавить:

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::bind('postActive', function ($value) {
        // scope то же оставляем, так как это хорошая практика. И потом может пригодиться в других местах
        return App\Models\Post::activeSlug($value)
               ->firstOrFail();
    });
}
```

В результате в маршруте будет:

```
Route::get('posts/{postActive}', [PostController::class, 'show']);
```

и в контроллере

```
public function show(Post $post): \Illuminate\View\View
{
    $post->load('reviews');
    return view('post.show', compact('post'));
}
```

Мы получаем более читабельный код, и во всех контроллерах ваши where заменятся на входной параметр, удаляя дубли. Далее вы просто одной строкой возвращаете `view`. В случае каких-либо изменений, вы просто в bind меняете условия и они применятся на все контроллеры где в маршруте используется поиск поста с ключом `postActive`

Comment: Laravel самостоятельно проверяет данные, которые приходят от пользователя (slug поста)? Или нужно отдельно валидацию делать? Очень хорошо объяснили, спасибо!

Comment: @РодионПоляков он сам делает по идее, так как в маршрут можно передать только строку. Укажите уточнение типа где `$value` и будет норм. `function (string $value)`.

Comment: @РодионПоляков https://laravel.com/index.php/docs/9.x/routing#implicit-model-binding-scoping вот базовый пример работы со slug в посте

Comment: function(string Post $post) разве это рабочий вариант? Я немного о другом. Нужно ли делать проверку, что slug может быть только из букв и - ? То есть, может ли недоброжелатель отправить туда что-то вредное.

Comment: вопрос. $post->load('reviews.user'); - так будет работать

Comment: @РодионПоляков Почему нет? попробуйте просто =)

Comment: @РодионПоляков  function(string Post $post) я не про это, а про bind в провайдере там указать  `function (string $value)`. Ну и отвечая на вопрос с валидацией, вам никто не запрещает её добавлять. Валидация не бывает лишней